# Crontab -; command

Tags: cron

I wrote `crontab-;` by mistake.

I tried to look for such a command online, but it doesn't seem to have any such command.

Now it's not listing any of my jobs using `crontab-l` . What do I do?

Comment: you can easily view your cron jobs in /etc/crontab file !

Comment: I'm not supposed to take pictures of the code at work :(

Comment: Syed Saad Ahmed I don't have root access

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @GhostCat sorry about the request and will not do it again. What I too needed is something like the text output on what she was trying (as you have requested).

Comment: @Gimhani Then just go ahead and delete the no longer required comments ;-)

Comment: Just wondering here. Did you type `crontab -l` or `crontab-l` (notice the space). If you typed the second, it will not do much.

Comment: No there was definitely a space.